# batch file not executing completely using task scheduler on windows

Tags: mysql, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have the following batch code, the code executes fine when I double click on the batch but when I try to run it through windows task scheduler, it only runs partially. I am unable to understand why.

Basically the code deletes all the rows ergo, runs until `mysql -e "DELETE  FROM software_it.hardware" -u root` and does not execute further. Any help would be great.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
mysql -e "DELETE  FROM software_it.hardware" -u root 
FOR %%f IN ("*.csv") DO (
  set old=%%~dpnxf
  set new=!old:\=\\!
  mysql -e "load data local infile '"!new!"' into table software_it.hardware  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 ROWS" -u root
  echo %%~nxf DONE
)
```

Comment: What I feel is that it does not understand that it has to execute from that specific folder!! Am I right?

Comment: try adding `cd %~dp0` as the first line. This will make sure it runs from the batch file directory instead of whatever default windows scheduler is using.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi, `cd /D "%~dp0"` is better as the current directory might reside on a different drive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When run from task scheduler it is likely that the 'current directory' will be different from that used when you run the script directly. I would therefore suggest adding the following **third line**:

```
IF /I "%CD%\" NEQ "%~dp0" PUSHD "%~dp0"
```